# Selecting Distinct Records Not In A Set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of customers with their customer contact options.

Customers can be contact in one of three ways via:

- **Telephone** (1)
- **SMS** (2)
- **Email** (3)

the FK id is in brackets.

If I wanted to pull out a list of distinct customer id's for both say SMS and Email I could do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
FROM contact_options 
WHERE contact_option_type_id IN (2,3)
```

But how do I do the inverse? Say I want a (`DISTINCT`) list of customers who don't have a Telephone contact. Can I do this without using a sub-query?

I realise the example is contrived, in practice I have very many different contact options (around 80).

Comment: `NOT IN (1)`???

Comment: So I'm going to assume that `NOT IN (1)` won't work because you actually have one row per contact option?  In which case you would need to use `NOT EXISTS` instead?

Comment: That's right. But NOT EXISTS requires a sub-query, and so the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM contact_options
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN contact_option_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

We can also try doing this using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM contact_options c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contact_options c2
    WHERE c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id AND c2.contact_option_type_id = 1);
```

Comment: Aggregation works. Postgresql allows you to convert a boolean to integer, so: SUM((contact_option_type_id=1)::integer) works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select distinct c.customer_id
from contact_options c
where not exists (select 1 
                   from contact_options
                   where customer_id = c.customer_id and 
                         contact_option_type_id  = 1
                  );
```

I don't think `exists` has performance issue if you have proper indexing delcared.

Comment: But I want to avoid using a sub-query, as it is high cost.

Comment: You cannot avoid a subquery. And it is not *high cost*. [it could even be cheaper]

Comment: @wildplasser I would say that we cannot avoid an _aggregation_.  All the records for a given customer group have to be inspected one way or the other.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, of course . I'm afraid your aggregation-method could be more costly than a subquery kind, given adequate indexes.